# .htaccess redirect only work for some pages but not others

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm having a weird issue where my .htaccess is only redirecting some pages whilst other pages aren't being redirected.

This is my current redirect condition:

```
<Ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Firefox/[1-3]\." [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Opera/9\..*Version/(1[10]|[1-9])\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Opera/[1-8]\." [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MSIE [1-8]\." [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.mytestingdomain.com/browser-upgrade.html [L,R=302]
</Ifmodule>
```

For example `www.mytestingdomain.com/about.html` will get redirected if I use IE8 but `www.mytestingdomain.com/search.html` won't get redirected if I use IE8.

I do have one or two `.htaccess` files in my `www` folder but those are just simple .htaccess files which prevent directory listings and shouldn't affect simple HTML pages.

My question is, why does my above redirect condition only work on some HTML pages and not others?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `"I do have one or two .htaccess files"`?

Comment: Well I have some sub folders and inside one or two of them I have an .htaccess file which prohibits them from being accessed via HTTP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't even know how any of it's redirecting because you have the pattern to only redirect root. I would change the `RewriteRule` so that the `pattern` will match any character in the URI.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Firefox/[1-3]\." [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Opera/9\..*Version/(1[10]|[1-9])\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Opera/[1-8]\." [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MSIE [1-8]\." [NC]
RewriteRule ^.* http://www.mytestingdomain.com/browser-upgrade.html [L,R=302]
```

Comment: I tried this, but for some reason now when I access my site with IE8 the browser just stays stuck in 'loading'

Comment: try clearing browser cache, although it shouldn't be since using 302.